# Django: How to access locale string among apps?

Tags: python, django, locale

There are two apps in my Django project root:

```
app1/
app1/locale/
app2/
app2/locale/
```

I want to use locale string form app1 in app2, so I can have no duplicated msgid.

Maybe, another solution is shared locale dir in project root dir:

```
app1/
app2/
locale/
```

but I have to rebuild many locale files ...

Answer (score 1):

You can make a symlink between them.